# Python Setuptools, easy_install setup mac

Tags: python

Okay, so I'm not sure at all what is going on here.  I just got my MAC, and I am trying to download and install setuptools, so I can download different python packages (using easy_install).  So, following the instructions here (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

1. I currently have version 2.6
2. I downloaded the following egg: setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg (md5)
3. I placed the file on my desktop (File Name: setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg.sh)
4. I navigate to the desktop on the directory, and use the following command line, as suggested by the above link:
   sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
5. I get an error: No such file or directory, so then I use this other command
   sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg.sh
6. Then, I get the following error:
   setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg.sh is not the correct name for this egg file.
   Please rename it back to setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg and try again.

I am really not sure at all what to do here. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**edit Try this from a command line**

Here is an easier thing to do that might work better for you. Open a terminal (Applications->Utilities->Terminal) and run this as a shell script. You can also run the individual commands.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~

# Downloads python setuptools for 2.6
curl -o setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg#md5=bfa92100bd772d5a213eedd356d64086

# installs it, will probably prompt you for password
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg

# clean up and delete egg
rm setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

**Stuff below was original response**

I just did this on my own Mac machine, and installation went off without a problem. Did you open a terminal to do this?

I downloaded setuptools to my Downloads folder, and then opened a terminal, and did this:

```
> cd ~/Downloads
> sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg 
Password:
Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Removing /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
setuptools 0.6c11 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mv setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg.sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```